# How to set multiple Animated.Values within onScroll using NativeDriver?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have an Animated.FlatList which must set two Animated.Values on scroll events, both with the y offset value and while using the NativeDriver. Maybe this could be done by adding an additional listener to the event. But, as I understand it, that listener wouldn't be running with the native driver, which is a requirement.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
<Animated.FlatList
  ...
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: animatedVal1,
          },
        },
      },
      { 
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: animatedVal2,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    {useNativeDriver: true},
  )}
  ...
/>
```

However, when a scroll is started, it throws the error:

`Invariant Violation: Event has less arguments than mapping, js engine: hermes`

I was looking at [`Animated.forkEvent()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#forkevent), but the available information on that API is very limited and I fail to figure it out.

Comment: you can try something like this: 

````

Answer (score 1):

Late but anyways.. when you are doing this `onScroll={Animated.event(...)}` you're basically doing `onScroll={event => {Animated.event(...)(event)}` so you could call multiple `Animated.event()` functions inside this event callback like:

```
<Animated.FlatList
  onScroll={event => {
    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: {
              y: scrollY,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      {useNativeDriver: true},
    )(event);

    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: {
              y: scrollYWithoutNativeDriver, // the other Animated.Value
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      {useNativeDriver: false},
    )(event);
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
const animatedVal1 = new Animated.Value(0);
const animatedVal2 = new Animated.Value(0);
const scrollY = Animated.add(animatedVal1,animatedVal2);

<Animated.FlatList
  ...
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: scrollY,
          },
        },
      }
    ],
    {useNativeDriver: true},
  )}
  ...
/>
```